# Libgdx screen keeping text on screen from main Game class

Tags: libgdx, screen-management

In my libGDX app I have some text running on the main Game class, and when I switch to a different screen the text is still there? Can anyone explain this please.
Also in my main class it is changing screens to a splash screen then to the screen I mentioned earlier. But the splash screen doesn't have the text on the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gdx.gl.glClear : as **.glClear** suggests, this function clears the screen before drawing the next frame.
It depends where do you instantiate your font object (as you're using libgdx I guess you use BitmapFont to create your font object).

An approach could be **to instantiate it in the main class** (the one that extends Game), and whenever you want to draw it on the screen, you call it in the render() method.

[image]

Assuming you're using **BitmapFont** to draw your text :

**MainClass**

```
private BitmapFont font;
private SomeScreen someScreen;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        font = new BitmapFont (path); 
        someScreen = new SomeScreen (this);
        (...)
        setScreen(someScreen);
    }

    public void drawText (String text) { 
      font.draw (spritebatch, text, x, y);
    }
```

**SomeScreen**

```
 public class SomeScreen implements Screen {

    // create reference to the main class
    MainClass main;

   // the contructor
   public SomeScreen (MainClass main) { 
   this.main = main;
   }

   @Override
   public void render(float delta) {
    // clean the screen
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    spritebatch.begin();
    main.drawText("your text here");
    spritebatch.end();
    }


}
```

**It can be also drawn during the main life-cycle :**

**MainClass**

```
  (...)
    @Override
    public void render () { 
     super.render(); // it draws whatever is in the render() method of the current screen
     font.drawText ("your text here"); // and then you draw your text (actually it doesn't make much sense)
    }
  (...)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` to your render function, as still clears the buffer, and alloys the new screen to load.

Comment: Elaborate on why this would fix the issue. This is a pretty short answer without a description.